# What does "(GameState *) new PlayingState()" do?

Tags: c++, oop

The line

```
(GameState *) new PlayingState()
```

Does not make much sense to me. Since `GameState*` is a pointer to a class and the `new` operator was employed it shows that `PlayingState()` is an object "newed" from another class. My questions come at the end of this post but first the definition of respective classes:

```
class GameState
{
public:
    virtual void onStart(StateBasedGame &game) = 0;
};

class PlayingState : public GameState, public EventSubscriber<sf::Event>
{
public:
    PlayingState();
    void onStart(StateBasedGame &game);
};
```

My questions:

1.Is it casting between classes? You can cast classes in C++ like casting data types in C? I thought C++ is much more "formal" and "redundant"?

2.Why do you want to do that? What's the point of such a conversion, what can the author achieve? I'm guessing it has something to do with the constructor.

3.To `new` something, shouldn't you go with this format?:

```
<class_type> <new_class_name> = new <class_type_name>
```

as in

```
GameState gameState = new PlayerState;
```

Apparently that's not the only way?

Comment: It is a cast *up* the inheritance hierarchy. You're right, I have no idea why they make the cast explicit. This is a public inheritance relationship, and there is no ambiguity in terms of multiple inheritance. Why didn't you show us the line of code *in context*?

Comment: _"What does `(GameState *) new PlayingState()` do?"_ - It kills kittens. Great example of how not to do something though.

Comment: "as in GameState gameState = new GameState" -- Are you coming from a different programming language such as Java or C#, perhaps? In C++, `new T` doesn't give you a value of type `T`, it gives you a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Without further context, this is odd to say the least (and I fail to imagine context where this would actually make sense).

First, you are right, in C++ style code you would use [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) or [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), depending on the situation, to cast between classes.

Second, since `PlayingState` inherits from `GameState`, pointers to `PlayingState` (as returned by `new PlayingState()`) are implicitly convertible to `GameState*`. The cast is not needed at all.

In this situation, the auther could have simply used:

```
GameState *gs = new PlayingState();
```

or even better, with modern C++:

```
auto gs = std::make_unique<PlayingState>()
```

(see [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto))

Answer (score 1):

```
(GameState *) new PlayingState()
```

Creates a new pointer of class PlayingState then casts it to class GameState.

```
class PlayingState : public GameState, public EventSubscriber<sf::Event> {
```

Is a class that extends GameState and another class. Data structures from parent types are also extended.

```
class GameState
```

Can be regarded as `interface` in Java/C#, as there were just pure virtual methods(`virtual <ret-type> <name>(<arguments>) = 0`).

virtual methods are stored in something called VMT(virtual method table), and your function call to any virtual method invokes methods in VMT by index.

You cannot initiate a pure virtual class just like you wouldn't initiate an interface. Therefore `GameState gameState = new GameState` is invalid. You also missed a pointer at `GameState gameState`.

Due to `PlayingState` is children of `GameState`, the `PlayingState` can casts into `GameState` in only pointer.

To dispose the object you have to `delete` it. `delete gameState` will do.

Do not attempt to `free` the `gameState` as `free`ing does not invoke the destructor routine.

**Edit**:

C++ also supports something called `RTTI`(Run-Time-Type-Information). In C++ there were `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast`.

The reason people recommend to use `dynamic_cast` for parent-child casting, is because basic run-time type checks can be done. Incomparable types are then able to be handled correct or another pointer-hell will be created.

To `dynamic_cast`, do:

```
dynamic_cast<GameState *>(new PlayingState())
```

You can `catch` the `bad_cast` if the both types do not insist any relationship.

```
try {
    dynamic_cast<GameState *>(new PlayingState())
} catch (std::bad_cast &oops) {
    // nightmare
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PlayingState` is a child class of `GameState`.

So the cast is ok. A child class is often converted in its base class, if you have code used to manipulate the base class of if you need to return a pointer of the base class.

You can also have things like:

```
Parent *p;

if (...) {
    p = new Child1();
} else {
    p = new Child2();
}

//do stuff with p
```

But the manual C-style cast is not necessary when converting the child pointer to the parent one.

The only example I can think of where it makes a bit of sense is if you want to call a function both present in the child and parent but not `virtual` (in your example all functions in the parent are virtual, though), and then you can do:

```
((GameState*) new PlayingState()) -> doStuff(...)
```

But it's a twisted way, and this would work as well:

```
GameState *g = new PlayingState();
g->doStuff();
```

In short without more code or context around the cast, I can only think it's unnecessary and a harmless redundancy.

---

As for cast operators, there are several in C++. `dynamic_cast` can be used to convert from parent to child (or even between parents of the same child) and safely check it's possible, but here it's not useful.